# How to search within an BelongsToMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

How do I search within a `BelongsToMany` Relationship within `laravel`?
Looks like I seem to be understanding something wrong

Below is my code:

```
public function search(Request $request, Project $post)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'query' => 'required'
  ]);

  $query = $request->input('query');
  $post  = Post::where('title', 'like', "%$query%")
               ->orWhere($post->tags()->role, 'like', "%$query$%")
               ->paginate(6);   

  return view('post.search', [
    'post' => $post,
  ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search into a relationship you may use `whereHas` or `orWhereHas` methods.

Your search function may be ok like this.

```php
public function search(Request $request, Project $post)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
       'query' => 'required'
    ]);
    $query = $request->input('query');
    $post = Post::where('title', 'like', "%$query%")
        ->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('role', 'like', "%{$query}%");
        })->paginate(6);   
    return view('post.search',[
        'post' => $post,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Code works, but you made an misstake : $query->where('role', 'like', "%{$query}%"); $query has to be $q